# get result of search in database postgresql and work with it every time

Tags: postgresql, java

I have a query who spend alot of time because there is thousand of ligne in the database, so I need if it's exist a method to put the result of the query some where and work with them the time i want. thanks

Comment: [Chapter 5. Issuing a Query and Processing the Result](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html)

Answer (score 0):

From PostgreSQL's point of view you can use [Materialized Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-materializedviews.html) or [Unlogged Tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-UNLOGGED)

For other solutions you can check different [caching mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing))